# The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

Tags: asp.net

i am having problem with my retrieving of date after the date fall after 12. for example : if i click from the calander extender: 2/7/2013 to 19/july/2013 , is will throw it me with this error : The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

this is my code:

```
var format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    DateTime one = DateTime.ParseExact(startdate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime two = DateTime.ParseExact(enddate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);



    if (two >= one)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=""catalog="";Integrated Security=True");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name,CLass, NRIC, StallNo, AmountSpent ,TimeDate=convert(nvarchar,timedate,103)  FROM StudentTransactions WHERE TimeDate BETWEEN '" + one + "' AND '" + two + "'", conn);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = reader;
        GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
        GridView1.Visible = true;
        GridView1.DataBind(); 
        conn.Close();
   }
```

Comment: _the date fall after 12_ what do you mean? in `2/7/2013` only year is after 12.

Comment: i mean that once i used the calender extender in asp.net, once i click : 12 /7/2013 till 19/7/2013 , it will prompt me that 19/7/2013 having this error :  The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`19/7/2013` cannot be parsed using `MM/dd/yyyy` format as `19` is not a valid month.
You may want to use `dd/MM/yyyy` instead.

Comment: after i have change it to dd/MM/yyyy , it gave me this error : The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Comment: @PorWeiting That is a separate issue. My guess is you should use parameters of `SqlCommand` for `one` and `two` instead of embedding dates in string. SQL Server input date formats are not guaranteed to match C# `ToString` output. However it would be processed correctly when using parameters.

Comment: is there any example to do so?

Comment: @PorWeiting Try using `BETWEEN @one AND @two` in your SQL string, then use `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@one", one)` and same for two. For any more details you will need a separate question.

Comment: After what u have told me to add, i encounter this error :Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BETWEEN'.

Comment: @PorWeiting make sure your query is like this `SELECT Name,CLass, NRIC, StallNo, AmountSpent ,TimeDate=convert(nvarchar,timedate,103)  FROM StudentTransactions WHERE TimeDate BETWEEN @one AND @two`.

Answer (score 0):

Date time format on local and Sever is different many times when you want to show date format in lables or texboxs and  Add update in database . After a long fatigue I got this solution:
First check the current date format like below:

```
lblMsg.Text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;  
if (lblMsg.Text == "dd/MM/yyyy")  
  txtd.Text = DateTime.Parse(dr["EventDate"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");  
else  
  txtd.Text = DateTime.Parse(dr["EventDate"].ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Add or Update: Similarly you can check either the current date format is dd/MM/yyyy OR "MM/dd/yyyy"

```
if (lblMsg.Text == "dd/MM/yyyy")
 usinfo.BDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDOB.Text.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
else
usinfo.BDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDOB.Text.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

lblMsg.Text = "";
```