# Converting date says its not supported in

Tags: c#

I am trying to Convert a date to a format of yyyyMMdd but it is saying that the supported date.

```
public override object StringToField(string from)
{
        try
        {
            string[] elements = from.Trim().Split(new char[] { ' ' });

            string date = RemoveNonNumericCharacters(elements[0]);

            return DateTime.ParseExact(date,"yyyyMMdd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Invalid date: {0}", from));
        }
 }
```

Its only trying to convert this so I do not understand 05/02/2018 22:28.

> The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar
>   System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

*Edit 2*

To show the remove numeric characters

```
private string RemoveNonNumericCharacters(string item)
{
        string result = "";

        foreach (char character in item)
        {
            if (char.IsNumber(character))
            {
                result += character;
            }
        }

        return result;
 }
```

**Edit 3**

Result of date before parse : 06022018

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584359/the-datetime-represented-by-the-string-is-not-supported-in-calendar-system-globa)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287304/the-datetime-represented-by-the-string-is-not-supported-in-calendar-system-globa)

Comment: @vahdet yes but im wanting to convert it to yyyyMMdd

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger and check what is the value of the _date_ variable before giving it as input to ParseExact? (Notice the Exact part)

Comment: @DavidB what is string date?

Comment: please see edit 3

Comment: you cannot parse "06022018" as in "yyyyMMdd" , it should be "20180602" if 6 is month

Comment: @DavidB sorry this is unrelated, but you should look into using `StringBuilder` in your `RemoveNonNumericCharacters` method. It would make it more efficient to do string manipulations.

Comment: it needs to be in that format for sage 200

Comment: then change it to `DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MMddyyyy" ...` counting 6 as month

Comment: @Amit its still not working cause the input date is of 05/02/2018 22:28

Comment: if input date is 05/02/2018 22:28, why `date` is 06022018 ? isn't it should be 05022018 ?

Comment: thats the orignal date that is being pulled in from the csv file the one that is to be converted @amit

Comment: so you are saying you have tried `return DateTime.ParseExact(date,"MMddyyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None);` and `return DateTime.ParseExact(date,"ddMMyyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None);` both and they are not working ?

Comment: correct @amit both of those do not work

Comment: that is really odd, I m having it working. I'm adding this as an answer. Let me know what error you are having while you use it.

Answer (score 3):

05/02/2018 isn't `yyyyMMdd`. Your `RemoveNonNumericCharacters` method probably translates it in 05022018, so year 0502, month 20, day 18. Change the string format you are passing to `ParseExact` to `ddMMyyyy` or `MMddyyyy` (unclear which one).

Answer (score 0):

In your 3rd edit you have shown the `date` ("06022018") string which is "MMddyyyy" format,

*Assuming in this date 6 is month (not a date)*

You cannot parse exact it to date by doing,

`DateTime.ParseExact(date,"yyyyMMdd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None);`

because then will be like you are make date with year:0602, Month:20, and date:18.

Here Month:20 isn't possible.

you need a string "20180602" instead of "06022018" to parse it the way you are trying to parse.

But if date string's format is fixed and you need it the way it is.

you need to change your parse exact like below,

`return DateTime.ParseExact(date,"MMddyyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None);`

and if 6 is date,

`return DateTime.ParseExact(date,"ddMMyyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None);`